What could cause a sudden and drastic shift in the position of the Earth's tectonic plates?
Before anyone points out any potential boneheadedness in my question -- I'm not a scientist, just someone with a story device that I want to run with and which I want to investigate the plausibility of.
I am writing a novel which involves a large worldwide tectonic shift that eventually ends up sliding the Earth's surface ninety degrees. That is, rotate the crust about an axis running through the equator. The current poles would wind up on the equator, and two points currently on the equator would wind up as the new poles. Meanwhile, the rest of Earth, besides the crust, would continue spinning, meaning that magnetic and celestial navigation would continue to work. (Though the maps being out of date would make this moot.)
Yes, this was inspired by that xkcd 'What If?' question.

Image from the whatif-xkcd article, created by Randal Monroe.
What would be a good way for the plates to shift the Earth's surface ninety degrees? It doesn't have to be overnight - it can be a somewhat gradual process, somewhere on the order of a couple of weeks, but not much longer.
Again before anyone asks, I am aware of the massive consequences this would have. Due to the 90-degree shift in the Earth's surface, we would have places like Central America freeze and Great Britain experience blistering tropical heat. And that's not considering the tectonic implications, which would involve lots of tsunamis, earthquakes and volcanic eruptions, or ice caps and glaciers melting faster than they can be replaced, or even the disruption of the natural cycle.
Then again, that's kind of the point of my story, to have a massive disaster that kills off billions of people. So keep that in mind when you answer.
Worldbuilding SE's response would be greatly appreciated.
Edit: Your valuable input has made me aware of the fact that having a ninety-degree shift of the Earth's surface is not tenable. As much as I would have liked to use that plot device, I still want a scientific base. Thus it is no longer usable. Still, thank you for your answers :)
Also, now that I think of it my idea is very similar to the Roland Emmerich film 2012, except without any Biblical-scale flooding and ensuing religious allusions. That movie, it seems, had about as much scientific base as my idea did -- essentially, mutating neutrinos cause the apocalypse. Just pointing something out.

90° in what direction? Sounds like a daft question I know but it's vitally important to understand the nature of the rotation you're looking for, we need a pole of rotation and a direction.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Nice picture, doesn't actually answer the question, what is the pole of rotation, we need co-ordinates, and what what is the sense of rotation, clockwise or counter?

"The massive consequences this would have" would be first and foremost that all the crust would be molten... For example, the Himalayas weight a lot and they have a lot of rotational kinetic energy, most of which would have to be dissipated as heat if you want to move them to 80 degrees north. Continents move sloooooowly; if you try to move them fast then climatic changes are the last of your worries.

If you'd said a couple of (dozen million) years, then..... Bit of a tall order you're asking us to justify, but then again, that's what this place is for.

What is your end goal here? If you are into this Atlassian task just for the sake of massive consequences, you could first consider other options as well (then again, you'd have to come up with them by yourself because we don't do brainstorming here :). Why this particular course of action?

you would be better off shifting the entire earth, nothing that is going to move the plates that fast relative ot the core is gong ot let them stay solid .

Remembering an old xkcd where he did a work on large-scale earthquakes, nothing in the universe can cause all tectonic plates to shift "at once" without causing the entire earth to explode.
The "recent" (moment) magnitude 9-9.5 earthquakes outside Japan and Thailand, caused the rotational north pole to shift in the range of 25 mm (or ~1 inch).
That was however mainly due to the displacement of earth mass, rather than a total global shift of tectonic plates.
The Chicxulub meteor - slightly larger than Mount Everest - which caused the extinction of the dinosaurs, would have had the energy of a magnitude 10-11 earthquake, creating large waves in lakes far away from Mexico.
Should the entire crust rotate on top of the mantle, that would require a magnitude 20 earthquake. However, the energy required would exceed the gravitational bonding, hence the exploding earth.
However, there is a constant "shift" of the surface relative to the earth's core: The core doesn't rotate at the same speed as the mantle and crust. This shift ("super-rotation") is believed to cause the drifting of the magnetic north pole. The difference in relative rotation speed varies at a ~70-year cycle.
If, however, the core would suddenly and very large shift its rotation (i.e. causing a sudden shift of the magnetic pole), that would "only" be the energy equivalent of a magnitude 15 earthquake. Thanks to the depth, it would (likely) not cause an earth-ripping event on the surface, but it would very certainly cause the surface to wobble.
Now, to get around all these physical limitations, one can resort to either
a) silently ignore them and just invent a cause, or
b) leave the characters clueless as to how it could have happened, or favorite
c) let the characters conclude that the physical limitations as currently understood by science were simply wrong and there are other - unknown - forces in play as well.

Subject to the stipulation that there has to be a person left alive to have a story about, nothing science-based whatsoever.
Neglecting losses to drag, which is a whopping big thing to neglect, you still have order of $10^{24} J/week$ to $10^{25} J/week$ deposited to the Earth to move the continents an earth radius or two relative to their normal position. (.01 Earth mass is mass, 2 earth radii is distance, 2 weeks is time, twice (once to start it, once to stop it): $2 \times .5mv^2$). This is around the amount of energy that the Earth would get if you put 100 suns in the sky.
Note this is an absolute extreme lower bound underestimate, because it ignores losses to viscous drag, inelastic collisions with solids, etc. I would fully expect the actual amount of energy deposited to Earth to be four or five orders of magnitude bigger. However, even in the extreme lower bound underestimate, all multicellular life is extinct by the end of the experiment.
Reality prohibits your fun. Do it with magic or Sufficiently Advanced Preposterous Technobabble instead.

So, since you've already read whatifxkcd, you also read the one about trying to stop continental drift (#41). And while with a vastly simplified model it might be possible to do so (for a few minutes), in actuality no mantle/tectonic geologist thinks so (even if they disagree on why that is.)
Tectonic plates are big and the forces involved in them are vast. This will not be an easy project by any stretch of the imagination.
Going from above, you run into the problem that rock really isn't rigid or solid on that scale. You also run into the problem that digging boreholes is hard, and we have never gotten even close to getting through the crust. Your attachment points will just rip off rather than anything happening.
You have to go in from below, aka manipulating the mantle somehow to somehow move everything in the right pattern for this to happen. I doubt anyone can figure out how you would manipulate the mantle in the first place, let alone how to make something that could perform the manipulation even in abstract.
The good news for you as a writer is that because (there's an xkcd for this) there's a 25km thick wall of rock between your characters and the mantle, they can't tell anything about what's going on. Even if someone is a geologist, taking seismograph data and turning it into models is not a fast process, and certainly couldn't be done in under two weeks with human civilization collapsing.


What could cause a sudden and drastic shift in the position of the
Earth's tectonic plates?

Easy: a sudden and drastic churning motion of the outer core, which drags the mantle and crust above it around the chosen pole of rotation.
What would cause a sudden and drastic churning motion of the outer core, then? Easy: magic.
Have a spacecraft of unknown origin plunge under the Pacific Ocean, bore a tunnel through the crust and mantle and impart the requisite motion to the Earth outer core, like the crank and wooden blades of an old-time washing machine spin the water and laundry inside.
When the lithosphere is an absolute mess under the Sun, have the spacecraft pop up her evil head again (like ships and spaceships, this spacecraft is a "she") and start planetforming the atmosphere and continents.
Added after @John 's comments:
I was too optimistic in estimating that external forces need only be exerted on the outer core: the stress induced throughout the mantle, if it were made to rotate rigidly with the outer core, seems to dwarf the pressure induced by gravity. So, I must modify the general picture: the evil spacecraft sort of turns the planet to a giant electric motor, with the inner core the stator and the outer core + mantle the rotor. This enables her to exert a controlled, slow-varying torque on the "rotor" by flowing direct current throughout it, thereby slowly tilting the direction of its angular momentum.
First, she makes the outer core superfluid at the interface with the inner core, so that they will slide w/out friction against each other. Initially, both "stator" (inner core) and "rotor" (rest of the planet) rotate around the polar axis at the same rate. Second, she creates a magnetic dipole at the center of the "stator" (Earth's CoM), in a fixed direction in the Equatorial plane: this will be the Zenithal axis $\overrightarrow{z}$. Define the East axis $\overrightarrow{e}$ as being also in the Equatorial plane and orthogonal to $\overrightarrow{z}$: together with the North axis $\overrightarrow{n}$, this defines an orthonormal FoR, originating at the Earth's CoM and spinning together with the inner core w/resp to Galilean FoR's: $2.\pi$ rad/sidereal day around the $\overrightarrow{n}$ axis.
Next, she converts part of the outer core and mantle to a giganormous solenoid of superconducting material encrusted in normal matter and starts flowing direct current in it. Because of the magnetic field attached to the "stator", this generates Laplace forces in every volume element of the "rotor"; the superconducting threads form a giant loop, so coiled that the result is a constant torque exerted on the "rotor", proportional to the intensity of the flowing current, directed along the $\overrightarrow{n}$ axis. A second coiling of superconducting threads, isolated from the first, allows a controlled amount of torque to be similarly generated along the $\overrightarrow{e}$ axis.
Thus, the angular momentum of the "rotor", which was initially along the $\overrightarrow{n}$ axis, must change over time: if a torque $\overrightarrow{T_r}$ of Laplace forces exists during the small interval of time $[t, t+\Delta t]$, the angular momentum of the "rotor" will increase vectorially from $\overrightarrow{J_r}$ to $\overrightarrow{J_r} + \Delta t .\overrightarrow{T_r}$. It does so as directed by the torque: normally to the $\overrightarrow{z}$ axis.
If, moreover, $\overrightarrow{T_r}$ is orthogonal to $\overrightarrow{J_r}$ all along, the "rotor" changes its axis of rotation w/out changing its spinning rate. The axis is still normal to $\overrightarrow{z}$, tilted by a small angle ~ ${T_r.\Delta t} \over {J_r}$ rad. Over time, say 13weeks (1/4yr), the total tilt will reach 90°: that is 1°/day on average, meaning the instantaneous rate of tilting grew from 0 to ~2°/day in 6.5wks, then back to 0 in an other 6.5wks. This is important because we are not particularly interested in moving the poles w/resp to the celestial sphere: we want the geographic pole to wander the Earth's surface, a full 90° to a given point on the former Equator (the one pointed at by $\overrightarrow{e}$, back then). As it turns out, both results are achieved simultaneously, as long as the tilting motion is slow and spans an integral number of (sidereal) days.
I am not sure the rotor also exerts Laplace forces on the stator; if it does, the total force should be zero, if only by symmetry. Also by symmetry, their total torque $\overrightarrow{T_s}$, if any, should be colinear with $\overrightarrow{T_r}$ and proportional to the intensity of the current flowing in the rotor.

it takes millions of years for forces in the core ot be transmitted through the mantle.

@John I do not see any relevance here. It take millions of years for convective plumes in the mantle, heated and made less dense at the surface of the core, to be pulled up to the crust according to Archimedes' principle; at this time scale, the mantle is a very viscous fluid. On the time scale required by the OP, a few weeks, the mantle is as rigid as the crust and "forces are transmitted" (actually, compression and shearing stresses are propagated) at the celerity of sound.

The process I describe is the (fluid) outer core initiating a rotational motion, then braking, over a few weeks; friction at the base of the mantle drags it en masse (with the lithosphere above it) a full 1/4 circle along a meridian, like an oceanic current drags a drifting boat.

except the force you would need to "drag" the mantle 90 degrees would remelt the planet. the mantle is rigid until you try to apply forces on such a scale. and if you need fives steps of magic to do it just say it is al done with magic. your not talking about transmiting a shock wave thorugh the mantle but a sheer wave the drastically exceeds its sheer strength.

@John maybe "drag" does not carry the right image. W/out wind, the friction forces applied to a drifting boat exert no mechanical work, they just force her motionless w/resp to the current. Meaning no heat is produced at the mantle-core interface. This is not 100% true if the current is accelerating. The average speed of the mantle at the interface is < (5600km/70 days) i. e. ~1m/s, resulting from a constant, horizontal acceleration of +/- 6.6muG during 2x35 days: ~60x the tidal acceleration of the Moon at sea level (which changes sign 150 times faster, however: every 5,5hrs).

@John Meaning the dissipated heat is in the same range as the tidal heating of the mantle. Actually, the "only" magic is the ability of the evil spacecraft to pour any desired density of kinetic energy out to its surrounding, then to suck it back in, in a thermodynamically reversible way.

Erratum. 6.6muG: read 66 nano-G with 1G=10m/s^2 not 6.6 micro-G, roughly the tidal acceleration of the Sun. Also 60% of the tidal acceleration of the Moon, +/- ~110nano-G.

except the mantle is already in motion so changing it will generate heat, the boat analogy only works if the boat is already moving in the dirrection of the current. and the average speed of the mantle now produces similiar motion on the order of billions of years, you need to produce the same motion in millions of orders of magnitude faster.

also to have the planet maintianing its current spin you can't change the rotational dirrection of the mantle, you can only change the position oif the crust without changing the mantles spin, which is a tremendous amount of motion across the mantle crust interface. more than enough to melt the crust from friction alone. you would be better off saying the alines just move the crust as it will produce the least heat and aline magic lets without drastically changing the layout if the plates, whcih yours does not.  but even then it is enough heat to melt the crust.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
